# scikit overfitting all the time

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

`Scikit` is overfitting when I am using it for machine learning. For example, I am using `decisiontree` for a regression.

The training set gave me 0.9998 for the `r_value`;
the test set gave me 0.3134 for the `r_value`;
after cross-validation, the test set gave me 0.1695 for the `r_value`.

And if I use `cross_val_predict` function, will I have to add the test set target value? Or will it give me an error? I am wondering how to avoid inputting test set target value?

```
dt=tree.DecisionTreeRegressor().fit(feature,target)

slope,intercept,r_value,p_value,std_err=stats.linregress(target,dt.predict(feature))
print r_value
slope,intercept,r_value,p_value,std_err=stats.linregress(target_test,dt.predict(feature_test))
print r_value

predicted=cross_validation.cross_val_predict(dt,     feature_test,target_test,cv=5)
slope,intercept,r_value,p_value,std_err=stats.linregress(target_test,predicted)
print r_value
```

Comment: What is weird?  All you're doing is calling a library function and printing the answer.  Why do you think you have a problem?

Comment: Because the training set gave me high r_value and the test set gave me low r_value. How can I get a similar r_values for the training set and test set?

Answer (score 0):

By default, DecisionTrees are built until all leaves are pure, so this is entirely expected. You should try to set `max_depth` or another regularization parameter, and set it using GridSearchCV.
Also, you might want to use a RandomForestRegressor or ExtraTreeRegressor instead of a single tree, which will give you better performance basically every time.
Have a look at the [user guide,](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/tree.html) in particular the tips on practical use.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to grid parameters. Besides, I am curious why my result got worse on test set if I used 'cross_val_predict' method? It tried 10 times.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please have a look at the cross-validation documentation. http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/cross_validation.html What you are doing right now doesn't make that much sense.